# Helix Toolkit in c# displaying ply point cloud

Tags: c#, point-clouds, helix-3d-toolkit

I have made a ply file with the help of [this wrapper](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/wrappers/csharp).

How I made the ply file is shown below:

```
using (var frames = pipeline.WaitForFrames())
{
    var colorFrame = frames.ColorFrame.DisposeWith(frames);
    var depthFrame = frames.DepthFrame.DisposeWith(frames);
    var points = pc.Process(depthFrame).As<Points>();
    // We colorize the depth frame for visualization purposes
    var colorizedDepth = colorizer.Process<VideoFrame>(depthFrame).DisposeWith(frames);

    // CopyVertices is extensible, any of these will do:
    var vertices = new float[points.Count * 3];
    // var vertices = new Intel.RealSense.Math.Vertex[points.Count];
    // var vertices = new UnityEngine.Vector3[points.Count];
    // var vertices = new System.Numerics.Vector3[points.Count]; // SIMD
    // var vertices = new GlmSharp.vec3[points.Count];
    //  var vertices = new byte[points.Count * 3 * sizeof(float)];
    points.CopyVertices(vertices);
    points.ExportToPLY("pointcloud.ply", colorFrame);
    // Render the frames.
    cloudPoints = importer.Load(@"pointcloud.ply");
}
```

Now I want to display it using the code:

```
private void Create3DViewPort()
{
    var hVp3D = new HelixViewport3D();
    var lights = new DefaultLights();
    HViewPort.Children.Add(lights);
    HViewPort.Children.Add(cloudPoints);
    this.AddChild(HViewPort);
}
```

But I get the error at the line `HViewPort.Children.Add(cloudPoints);`. It is saying that:

> It cannot convert Systems.Windows.Media.Media3D.Model3D to Systems.Windows.Media.Media3D.Visual3D.

Can someone help me how I can display the point cloud using the helix toolkit?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the way but I can show the point cloud in the ply file.
The code:

```
Model3DGroup model1 = import.Load("pointcloud.ply");
model.Content = model1;
```

XAML:

```
<HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2.4,1,0,-0.4" >
            <HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera />
            </HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D.Camera>
            <HelixToolkit:DefaultLights></HelixToolkit:DefaultLights>
            <ModelVisual3D x:Name="model"></ModelVisual3D>
        </HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D>
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous advice really helped. However, it is necessary to create an instance of the **importer** class and in the **XAML** file the compiler asks you to place the model declaration before the camera is declared.

**cpp file:**

```
ModelImporter importer = new ModelImporter();
Model3DGroup model=importer.Load("model_file.ply");
MyModel.Content = model;
```

**XAML:**

```
<helix:HelixViewport3D x:Name="viewPort3d">
    <ModelVisual3D x:Name="MyModel"/>
    <helix:HelixViewport3D.Camera>
        <PerspectiveCamera UpDirection="-0.00794080933244957, 0.909926622339627, 0.414693242656239"
                           LookDirection="49.636719684, -2387.8047, -29918.6652549283"
                           Position="-48.6367196, 5688.80470553634, 29917.665254"/>

    </helix:HelixViewport3D.Camera>
</helix:HelixViewport3D>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible at the moment to show some ply files in the helix toolkit
([see Helix Wiki](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/wiki/Features-(WPF)#import)).

You can display a ply file with the code below, but you will not see the item you expect

```
Model3DGroup group = new Model3DGroup();
var hpVp3D = new HelixViewport3D();
ModelVisual3D visual3D = new ModelVisual3D();
var lights = new DefaultLights();
ModelImporter importer = new ModelImporter();
Model3D element;

element = importer.Load(@"pointcloud.ply")
group.Children.Add(element);

visual3D.Content = group;

hVp3D.Children.Add(visual3D);
hVp3D.Children.Add(lights);

this.AddChild(hVp3D);
```